# Countdown hours bug (NSDate and Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, countdown

I have a little problem with my countdown, in fact everything works fine but the hours are not in the right format that is to say, it shows me this:

> 03: 94: 20: 38

but I 'it would appear to me the real countdown of the hours that is to say:

> 03: 22: 20: 38

My code :

```
 - (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)tmr
{
    self.dateContest.hidden = NO;
    NSTimeInterval iv = [self.date timeIntervalSinceNow];
    int d = iv / 86400;
    int h = iv / 3600; // My problem
    int m = (iv - h * 3600) / 60;
    int s = iv - h * 3600 - m * 60;
    self.dateContest.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", d, h, m, s];
    if (d + h + m + s <= 0) {
        [tmr invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use NSDateFormatter?

Comment: Obviously you have three days and 22 hours which equals 94 hours. And 94 is what your code calculates. Any reason why you are not using NSInteger? And your test for expiry is very dubious. Either convince me that it is correct, or check iv < 0 instead of d + h + m + s <= 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to minus that day hours as well

```
int d = iv / 86400;
    int h = (iv / 3600) - (d * 24); 
int m = (iv - (h + d * 24) * 3600) / 60
int s = lroundf(iv) % 60
```

Comment: it works but there is just a problem of minutes now (4325 min)

Comment: thank you very much it works and last small problem, for seconds how do because it does not work?

Comment: it does not work, there is an error (invalid operand)

Comment: sorry I forgot about double, now check